# C# - string to keywords

Tags: c#, string, list, keyword

**What is the most efficient way to turn string to a list of words in C#?**

For example:

```
Hello... world 1, this is amazing3,really ,  amazing! *bla*
```

should turn into the following list of strings:

```
["Hello", "world", "1", "this", "is", "amazing3", "really", "amazing", "bla"]
```

Note that it should support other languages other than English.

I need this because I want to collect a list of keywords from specific text.

Thanks.

Comment: Your looking to tokenize a string. Check out James' answer.

Comment: How much text do you have to process?  A few thousand words or millions?

Comment: Actually maximum could be like 100 words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using regular expressions? You could make the expression arbitrarily complex, but what I have here should work for most inputs.

```
new RegEx(@"\b(\w)+\b").Matches(text);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
char[] separators = new char[]{' ', ',', '!', '*', '.'};  // add more if needed

string str = "Hello... world 1, this is amazing3,really ,  amazing! *bla*";
string[] words= str.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: @Alon, Add them to the list of seperators.

Answer (score 2):

You need a [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis).